# How to figure out that I'm onto ice tile?

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap

It might be very silly question but serfing for two hours still can't find an answer.

I'm trying to replicate battle city.

I've made level with TileMap. But can't figure out how to know that my tank is onto ice tile to slow him up?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used the TileMap myself but reading the docs I can tell you this.

First of all you need a TileMapCollider Component, then you need to make a script and add it to the tilemap game object. The script should use `OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)`

then feed `collision.gameObject.transform.position` to `tilemap.WorldToCell()` and use the result of that to get the specific tile you are on with `tileMap.GetTile()` that returns a TileBase class that has a tile name that you can use to determine if it is ice or not. Like I sad I've never used the TileMap so there might be a way better way of doing it. :)

Comment: But if I add TileMapCollider to tile my tank get stucked against the ice tile.

Comment: @SergeyPopov you could set the Collider to be a trigger and use OnTriggerEnter or OnTriggerStay then. I did not know you can add colliders to individual tiles.

Comment: Already did but thanks. Posted an answer below!

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured out how to do it!:)

It was easier than I thought.

Tiles have TileCollider2D it inherits all the stuff from Collider 2D.
So You can turn on a trigger.
And in the player's script write down event Monobehavior methods OnEnterTrigger2D OnExitTrigger2D. Where I change speed if I'm onto the ice tile:)
Thanks for an answer though!:)